# Can I use uWSGI emperor to manage a background process?

Tags: python, ubuntu, uwsgi

I'm using uWSGI in emperor mode to run a number of web applications.  Now I want to create a new application purely for housekeeping purposes - it will be continually monitoring a backend database for certain conditions.

I'm on Ubuntu, so I *could* manage this process using **upstart**, but I like the benefits of uWSGI - automatic code reloading and so on.

So is it possible to have a uWSGI vassal that *isn't* a WSGI application?  And if so, what would my configuration `.ini` file have to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the directives described here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html

are enough to spawn a vassal. You will end with a master managing your daemon/daemons.

The same is true for cron directives too

Comment: Ah, that sounds like what I'm looking for.